# I cant get divs to display in line in firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm building a coming soon page, and i inserted a counter in the page middle, is working fine on internet explorer and chrome, but when i use the Firefox, the browser can't display the counter divs inline, what am i doing wrong?

Firefox

[image: http://i.imgur.com/AIadZm3.png]

Chrome

[image]

HTML Code

```
#line = wrapper
#square = counter elements wrapper

 <div id="line">
    <!-- Counter -->
    <div id="days" class="square backdays"></div>
    <div id="hrs" class="square backhrs"></div>
    <div id="min" class="square backmin"></div>
    <div id="sec" class="square backsec"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

Line code:

```
#line{
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

Square code

```
.square {
    width: 210px;
    height: 226px;
    float: left;
}
```

The elements(Title, counter, subscription area) are all centered in the middle.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: could you please add a fiddle too???

Comment: Your text looks bigger, did you accidentally expand it in browser?

Comment: Try setting the width of #line to 100%. I think there's not enough space for the squares to be on one line.

Comment: Reset the browser hitting Ctrl+0 and see the zooming is normal first in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

i changed the line code and now is working

```
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 100;  
  top:45%;  
  left:50%;  
  margin:-100px 0 0 -460px;  
  width:100%;
```

I'm not using percentages anymore